# Google font with font-weight: bold not have same size

Tags: css, fonts

I have a problem with Google Fonts and font-weight.

My Problem is that I have a div with content editable text where the user can edit the **font weight**, but the font weight bold CSS property is rendered different between browsers...

Can I have any option in CSS to make the *font-weight:bold* in the same size?

If you check the example Fiddle in FF, Chrome or Safari, you will see that the text is in two lines in FF and Safari, and with one line in Chrome:

https://jsfiddle.net/zgfdudmy/

Here you have the code tested:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy);

div
{
  z-index: 2;
    font-family: Satisfy;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    width: 249px;
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}

text-div {
    -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;
    display: block;
}

*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, a, button, I, input {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

*, :active, :hover {
    outline: 0!important;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent!important;
}

.text-align-left {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="text-div" style="padding: 0px; display:inherit; transform:matrix(0.9903,-0.139173, 0.139173,0.9903,0,0); -webkit-transform:matrix(0.9903,-0.139173, 0.139173,0.9903,0,0);" spellcheck="false">
       <span style="font-weight: bold;">Chema Roldán</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That font doesn't have a bold variant in the family (according to 'https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Satisfy'.  So you're asking the browser to interpret `font-weight: bold`.  With webfonts you really should pick a family that includes a stronger or bold variant if you need it and specify `font-family` vs. `font-weight` in your css, or use the font-weight identifier (usually a number like 200-700) if included in the family.

Comment: Thanks, but what happens if a don't have the option to include the weight font?

Comment: Like I said, the browser will try and interpret the weight, which is why you're having inconsistencies across browsers.

Comment: Do I have any option to solve this situation? Thanks

Comment: A) choose a different font family that includes the variants you need. B) Contact the foundry and pay them to create a bold version.  It should be worth mentioning that a lot of hand-style fonts like this may not have bold or other variants... it's not a popular variant for hand-script.  It may be that the designer didn't want people bolding it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [numbers](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_font-weight&preval=900) instead of `bold` for your font size units. Then you'll be dealing with pixel sizes.

> [700 is the same as bold](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp)

Comment: Thanks, but this not solved my problem, you can test here: https://jsfiddle.net/zgfdudmy/3/